# I have a small problem with a horizontal line in a hierarchical folder tree

Tags: reactjs, treeview, binary-search-tree

I have a small problem with a horizontal line in a hierarchical tree of folders in ReactJS, it seems that when I open a subfolder, the line that points to it goes at the bottom, when it should stay pointing to the open folder.

[ROOT Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbNjo.png)

[ROOT Folder open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js7cA.png)

[Subfolder open (error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOuMw.png)

main component of the folders:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Carpeta = ({ carpeta, data, onFolderSelect }) => {
    const [abierta, setAbierta] = useState(false);
    const [seleccionada, setSeleccionada] = useState(false);

    const toggleAbierta = () => {
        setAbierta(!abierta);
    };

    const toggleSeleccion = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        setSeleccionada(!seleccionada);
        onFolderSelect({ IdFolder: carpeta.IdFolder, Name: carpeta.Name, IdParent: carpeta.IdParent });
    };

    const carpetaContieneSubcarpetas = (idCarpeta, data) => {
        return data.some(subcarpeta => subcarpeta.IdParent === idCarpeta);
    };

    const LineaConexion = () => {
        if (carpeta.IdParent) {
            return (
                <svg
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: '-20px',
                        width: '20px',
                        bottom: '8px',
                        height: '100%',
                    }}
                >
                    <line
                        x1="10"
                        y1="0"
                        x2="10"
                        y2="100%"
                        stroke="#555"
                        strokeWidth="2"
                    />
                    <line
                        x1="10"
                        y1="100%"
                        x2="20"
                        y2="100%"
                        stroke="#555"
                        strokeWidth="2"
                    />
                </svg>
            );
        }
        return null;
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
            <LineaConexion />
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <div style={{ cursor: 'pointer', userSelect: 'none' }} onClick={toggleAbierta}>
                    {abierta ? ' ' : ' '}
                    <span style={{ fontWeight: seleccionada ? 'bold' : 'normal' }}>{carpeta.Name}</span>
                </div>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={seleccionada} onChange={toggleSeleccion} style={{ marginLeft: '10px', marginTop: '5px' }} />
            </div>
            {abierta && carpetaContieneSubcarpetas(carpeta.IdFolder, data) && (
                <ul style={{ listStyleType: 'none', paddingLeft: '20px', marginTop: '5px' }}>
                    {data
                        .filter(subcarpeta => subcarpeta.IdParent === carpeta.IdFolder)
                        .map(subcarpeta => (
                            <li key={subcarpeta.IdFolder}>
                                <Carpeta carpeta={subcarpeta} data={data} onFolderSelect={onFolderSelect} />
                            </li>
                        ))}
                </ul>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Carpeta;
```

I tried changing to absolute, flex, relative, among many other changes but without good results.